# for loop multiple variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I have the following code that I need to use multiple times (at least 10 times):

```
if([_btn_gv_tl1 isEqualToString:@"on"])
{
    btn_gv_tl1.tag = 1;
    UIImage *btnIMG_gv_tl1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stateOn.png"];
    [btn_gv_tl1 setImage:btnIMG_gv_tl1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else
{
    btn_gv_tl1.tag = 0;
    UIImage *btnIMG_gv_tl1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stateOff.png"];
    [btn_gv_tl1 setImage:btnIMG_gv_tl1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The problem is that I use multiple variables. _btn_gv_tl1 is a string, btw_gv_tl1 is a button, etc.

I named my variables from _btn_gv_tl1 to _btn_gv_tlx with all the variables.
How can I use the code above multiple times without copying and pasting the code? I think it is much nicer to create a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Also learn about functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store those items in `NSArray`. You can read about them [here](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray.html). If you do so, it's easy know to iterate thorough this objects:

```
for (id object in objectsArray) {
  // Do anything with ths objects
}
```

## Update

Do the multi-dimensinal array (array of arrays) like this:

```
NSArray *array = @[@[object1, object11, object111],
                   @[object2, object22, object222], 
                   @[object3, object33, object333]];
```

Comment: Thank you but than i can only get one variable in the for loop (the string _btn_gv_tl1 is in the array but the button btn_gv_tl1 is not?)

Also the btnIMG_gv_tl1 needs to count up every time the loop continues

Comment: So create two dimensional array...  Or `NSDictionary` with key `_btn_gv_tlX` and value `btn_gv_tlX`...

Comment: Ok, got the idea but this was an example of 2 variables... there are more (minimum of 3)...

Comment: Thanks! i'm going to look at that!

Comment: On some stage you will have to do 10 conditions or so on, but you can pass some identifier (number, string) which will do the process automatically.